# Which code i should return when request doesn't pass cross site forgery attack validation

Tags: security, antiforgerytoken, cross-site

I filter HTTP requests by referrer field to prevent cross site forgery attacks. I know it is a bad idea and i already use ASP.NET MVC built-in anti-forgery mechanism but our customer has special security utility which checks cross-site forgery attacks by change referrer field of HTTP request.

My question is what i need to do when i receive domain which is not allow? What http code to return and which page i should show to user?

Should it be custom page like 404 not found or just redirect to main page?

What is common practice?

Comment: As long as you're confident that this response will only ever be given to potential attackers, return something that gives them no information about what's happened.  A 404 (or even a 500, as a decoy) will not help them improve their attack.

Comment: @RichieHindle No, this response may be given to users who just clicked link to our application on other resource(with another domain).

Answer (score 0):

"403 Forbidden" and provide a HTML body directing users to your home page.

An attacker can't see the status code of a CSRF attack during POST (due to Same Origin Policy) so the HTTP code is of no consequence apart from serving to inform real users.